# Click event is lost for element with animated images inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, onclick

I have written some code which produces simple animations based on cycling through a load of images, showing one image at a time with the rest hidden.  Each frame is shown for 50 milliseconds.

The HTML of the animated element is like this:

```
<a href="/" id="owl">
  <img class="owl frame active-frame" style="" src="http://example.com/image1">
  <img class="owl frame" style=" display:none;" src="http://thereisspacehere.org/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/animation/owl/2.jpg">
  <img class="owl frame" style=" display:none;" src="http://example.com/image2">
  <img class="owl frame" style=" display:none;" src="http://example.com/image3">
</a>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
#owl {
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:13px;
  width:154px;
  height:170px;
}
.owl {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:154px;
  height:170px;
}
```

The #owl element is positioned absolutely within a relatively positioned div.

The #owl element is a link to '/', but clicking on the animation does nothing.  This code:

```
$('#owl').click(function(){
  console.log('Clicked');
});
```

Never gets executed when you click on it.  Likewise, attaching an `onclick` event directly to the html of the element doesn't restore the clickability.

If I make the `<a>` element bigger than the animated frames inside it, the portion that extends beyond the animation *does* retain its click event, and the code above runs, and the link is followed.

Why have I lost my click event?  How can I get it back, or how can I work around the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Edit - here's the code that creates the animation.  Apologies for length!

```
Animation = {
    direction: 1,
    iterations: 0,
    maxIterations: 30,
    intervalId: false,
    element: '',
    active: false,
    cycle: function(element, iterations){
        this.element = element;
        $(element).addClass('animation');
        this.maxIterations = iterations;
        if (!this.active){
            this.intervalId = setInterval(function(){ Animation.changeFrame(Animation.element);},50);
            this.active = true;
        }
    },
    changeFrame: function(element){
        if (this.iterations > this.maxIterations){
            this.stop();
            this.revertToStart(element);
            this.active = false;
            this.iterations = 0;
        }
        var el = $(element);
        currentFrame = el.children('.active-frame');
        if (this.direction === 1){
            nextFrame = currentFrame.next('.frame');
        }else{
            nextFrame = currentFrame.prev('.frame');
        }
        if (nextFrame.length == 0){
            this.direction = this.direction ? 0 : 1;
            if (this.direction === 1){
                nextFrame = currentFrame.next('.frame');
            }else{
                nextFrame = currentFrame.prev('.frame');
            }
        }
        currentFrame.hide().removeClass('active-frame');
        nextFrame.show().addClass('active-frame');
        this.iterations++;
    },
    stop: function(){
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    },
    revertToStart: function(element){
        $(element).children('.frame').removeClass('active-frame');
        $(element).children('.frame').hide();
        $(element).children('.frame:first').show().addClass('active-frame');
    }
};
$(function(){
    $('#owl .frame:first').addClass('active-frame');
    $('#owl').mouseover(function(){
        Animation.cycle('#owl', 29);
    });
    $('#owl').click(function(){
        console.log('hey');
    })
});
```

Comment: You are probably preventing event bubbling from some other click event handler. Show us more code (the animation part).

Comment: Works for me. Probably js not see `#owl` in the execution point. Add `console.log($('#owl').length);` near click handler and see is shown on console window. If 0 then you must wrap js with `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Lolo, $('#owl').length is 1.  Code is wrapped in $(function(){...

Comment: Jan, there are no other click event handlers on the element.  I can show you the animation code but it is a bit long...

Comment: In that case there is probably something with bubbling as @JanHančič says. Try changing selector to `$('#owl, #owl img')`

Comment: @Lolo, thanks, already tried that, no click event still. Code used to animate elements is provided in my edit.

Comment: There must be some code that is handling clicks on your images. Or possibly clicks aren't registered because you are hiding/showing images so fast (but that's just a wild guess). Can you setup a working example somewhere (http://jsfiddle.net/ for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why click doesn't work, but I have solution. You can add additional transparent element on the top, and then everything will work.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/pJ5sE/1/

Comment: Well, this solves the problem so I'm marking it as correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `.click()` wrapped within `$(document).ready({})` because otherwise the code get's executed before the DOM is fully loaded which means he is not able to find `$('#owl')` at this point !
You should also pass the event to the click method to use `e.preventDefault()` to make sure nothing is added to your URL !

Answer (score 0):

Note :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#owl').click(function(){
    console.log('Clicked');
    return false
  });
})
```

return false to stop browser action when you click in

Comment: But the point is that I want the default browser action to happen, but it is not happening!